No GPU output with dedicated AMD 7900XT on Ubuntu 24.04
Edit: Answer is in the comment section below.
I have a PC with essentially 2 GPUs. One dedicated (AMD 7900 XT) and one integrated GPU (AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D). The integrated GPU works flawlessly. I have the issue that I cannot use my dedicated GPU. I already tried to change the BIOS Setting in my Motherboard to disable integrated graphics but that didn't work. The result is still a black screen.
What I want: Use my dedicated AMD 7900 XT as an output instead of my integrated AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D.
This is the output of xrandr --listproviders:
Providers: number : 0
This is the output of inxi -Fxxxrz
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
    clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: gnome-shell
    tools: gsd-screensaver-proxy dm: GDM3 v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING B650-PLUS WIFI v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> part-nu: SKU uuid: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1811 date: 10/07/2023
Battery:
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 2S
    serial: <filter> charge: 55% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes
    status: discharging
  Device-2: wacom_battery_0 model: Wacom Intuos BT S serial: N/A
    charge: 100% status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 4 rev: 2 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 8 MiB L3: 96 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 802 high: 3666 min/max: 400/5050 cores: 1: 400 2: 400
    3: 400 4: 400 5: 3666 6: 400 7: 400 8: 400 9: 400 10: 400 11: 400 12: 400
    13: 400 14: 400 15: 3575 16: 400 bogomips: 134390
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX/7900M] vendor: ASRock
    driver: N/A arch: RDNA-3 pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 03:00.0
    chip-ID: 1002:744c class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AMD Raphael vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel
    arch: RDNA-2 pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: HDMI-A-1
    empty: DP-1,Writeback-1 bus-ID: 0e:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:164e class-ID: 0300
    temp: 37.0 C
  Device-3: Logitech StreamCam
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo type: USB rev: 3.2
    speed: 5 Gb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 2-1:2 chip-ID: 046d:0893 class-ID: 0300
    serial: <filter>
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: radeon
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 model: Samsung S24E650 serial: <filter> res: 1920x1080
    dpi: 94 size: 521x293mm (20.51x11.54") diag: 598mm (23.5") modes:
    max: 1920x1080 min: 720x400
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: amd radeonsi platforms: device: 0 drv: radeonsi
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: radeonsi wayland: drv: radeonsi x11:
    drv: radeonsi inactive: gbm
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi
    raphael_mendocino LLVM 17.0.6 DRM 3.57 6.8.0-31-generic)
    device-ID: 1002:164e display-ID: :0.0
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 31 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 03:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:ab30 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0e:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1640 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0e:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403
  Device-4: Logitech StreamCam
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo type: USB rev: 3.2
    speed: 5 Gb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 2-1:2 chip-ID: 046d:0893 class-ID: 0300
    serial: <filter>
  Device-5: Elgato Systems GmbH Wave:3 driver: snd-usb-audio type: USB
    rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-2:2 chip-ID: 0fd9:0070
    class-ID: fe01 serial: <filter>
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-31-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: d000 bus-ID: 0a:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8125
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network
    vendor: AzureWave driver: rtw89_8852be v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: c000 bus-ID: 0b:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:b852 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp11s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    rev: 1.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-5:3 chip-ID: 13d3:3571
    class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.3
    lmp-v: 12 sub-v: b20f hci-v: 12 rev: dbc6 class-ID: 6c0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.64 TiB used: 14.64 GiB (0.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Corsair model: MP600 CORE XT size: 3.64 TiB
    speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: ELFMC1.0
    temp: 31.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.88 TiB used: 14.61 GiB (0.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 32.5 MiB (33.9%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 40.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 37.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 1784 pm: dpkg pkgs: 1772 pm: snap pkgs: 12
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.sources
    1: deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.sources
    1: deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
    1: deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble noble-updates noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    2: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Memory: total: 64 GiB available: 62.02 GiB used: 4.47 GiB (7.2%)
  Processes: 364 Power: uptime: 39m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: deep
    wakeups: 0 hibernate: platform Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5)
    default: graphical
  Compilers: N/A Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21 running-in: gnome-terminal
    inxi: 3.3.34

This is the output of glxinfo -B:
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
    Device: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi, raphael_mendocino, LLVM 17.0.6, DRM 3.57, 6.8.0-31-generic) (0x164e)
    Version: 24.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 512MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 98 MB, largest block: 98 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 31467 MB, largest block: 31467 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 98 MB, largest block: 98 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 31467 MB, largest block: 31467 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 98 MB, largest block: 98 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 31467 MB, largest block: 31467 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 512 MB
    Total available memory: 32263 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 98 MB
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi, raphael_mendocino, LLVM 17.0.6, DRM 3.57, 6.8.0-31-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

This is the output of sudo lshw -c video:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX/7900M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:f00-eff iomemory:f80-f7f ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcbfffff memory:fcc00000-fcc1ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raphael
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:79 memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-901fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc600000-fc67ffff

This is the output of sudo dmesg | grep amdgpu:
[    4.931840] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    4.931858] amdgpu: vga_switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_.ATPX handle
[    4.932039] amdgpu: ATPX version 1, functions 0x00000000
[    4.943564] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[    4.943576] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    4.943673] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    4.948115] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[    4.948119] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-D70401-103
[    4.956060] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: CP RS64 enable
[    4.961590] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:jpeg_v4_0_early_init [amdgpu]] JPEG decode is enabled in VM mode
[    4.963136] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
[    4.963160] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: MEM ECC is not presented.
[    4.963162] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SRAM ECC is not presented.
[    4.963203] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 20464M 0x0000008000000000 - 0x00000084FEFFFFFF (20464M used)
[    4.963204] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 512M 0x00007FFF00000000 - 0x00007FFF1FFFFFFF
[    4.963218] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek amdgpu(+) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump snd_hwdep edac_mce_amd rtw89_8852be rtw89_8852b snd_pcm kvm_amd rtw89_pci snd_seq_midi rtw89_core snd_seq_midi_event amdxcp kvm snd_rawmidi drm_exec uvcvideo gpu_sched irqbypass drm_buddy videobuf2_vmalloc crct10dif_pclmul drm_suballoc_helper uvc polyval_clmulni snd_seq videobuf2_memops drm_ttm_helper btusb polyval_generic mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 ttm sha256_ssse3 btrtl snd_seq_device sha1_ssse3 snd_timer btintel videodev aesni_intel drm_display_helper btbcm btmtk eeepc_wmi asus_nb_wmi mfd_aaeon crypto_simd bluetooth cryptd asus_wmi cec videobuf2_common snd ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap rc_core cfg80211 rapl ecdh_generic platform_profile wmi_bmof mc ccp i2c_piix4 k10temp i2c_algo_bit soundcore libarc4 ecc input_leds joydev
[    4.963346]  amdgpu_bo_init+0xbe/0x110 [amdgpu]
[    4.963514]  gmc_v11_0_sw_init+0x217/0x2a0 [amdgpu]
[    4.963674]  ? nbio_v4_3_enable_doorbell_aperture+0x5a/0x190 [amdgpu]
[    4.963822]  amdgpu_device_ip_init+0xeb/0x860 [amdgpu]
[    4.963972]  amdgpu_device_init+0x99f/0x1150 [amdgpu]
[    4.964115]  amdgpu_driver_load_kms+0x1a/0x1c0 [amdgpu]
[    4.964272]  amdgpu_pci_probe+0x1c1/0x600 [amdgpu]
[    4.964461]  ? __pfx_amdgpu_init+0x10/0x10 [amdgpu]
[    4.964605]  amdgpu_init+0x69/0xff0 [amdgpu]
[    4.964824] [drm:amdgpu_bo_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Unable to set WC memtype for the aperture base
[    4.964972] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* sw_init of IP block <gmc_v11_0> failed -22
[    4.965132] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[    4.965134] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    4.965136] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
[    4.965470] amdgpu: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22
[    4.965863] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    4.967563] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[    4.967565] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 102-RAPHAEL-008
[    4.997618] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.997621] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature disabled as experimental (default)
[    4.997649] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 512M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F41FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    4.997651] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[    4.997719] [drm] amdgpu: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[    4.997721] [drm] amdgpu: 31751M of GTT memory ready.
[    4.998464] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    5.088398] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[    5.094241] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[    5.094244] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[    5.095419] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
[    5.096673] snd_hda_intel 0000:0e:00.1: bound 0000:0e:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    5.135951] amdgpu: HMM registered 512MB device memory
[    5.136901] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[    5.136913] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Total number of KFD nodes to be created: 1
[    5.137195] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[    5.137318] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x164e:0x1002]
[    5.137321] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:164e
[    5.137332] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 2, active_cu_number 2
[    5.137337] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[    5.137339] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[    5.137341] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    5.137342] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    5.137344] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    5.137346] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    5.137347] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    5.137349] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    5.137351] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    5.137352] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    5.137354] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[    5.137356] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec_0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
[    5.137357] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
[    5.137359] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
[    5.137361] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
[    5.138175] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.57.0 20150101 for 0000:0e:00.0 on minor 1
[    5.143561] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.143565] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    5.390576] amdgpu 0000:0e:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc31_disable_crtc line:136

What stands out to me is this part from the above output:
[    4.965132] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[    4.965134] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    4.965136] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
[    4.965470] amdgpu: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22

Not sure if this means that the dedicated GPU isn't loading or something else.
I have seen the following guide on how to get graphics for an AMD 7900XT: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=370633#AMD-7900
I did not follow that guide as I am on a newer version with the Kernel being greater than 6.0 (It's 6.8.0-31) and Mesa (at least on the integrated GPU) being greater than 22.0 (It's 24.0.5).
Would I really need to install the newest firmware from here and do an update-initramfs just like explained in the guide?

The solution is to turn off Resizable BAR in the BIOS Settings (I have an ASUS Motherboard).

Thank you!
I had the exact same problem with my AMD Radeon RX 7800XT OC, and turning off Resizable BAR in BIOS fixed it for me as well. Yes, I too have an ASUS Motherboard.
But since Resizable BAR enables the CPU to communicate with all of the VRAM at once, instead of chunks limited to 256MB, this will likely hamper the performance on more demanding games. So, a long term solution in which both work is desirable.
Have you found any information on why our AMD Radeon GPUs fails in Linux when BAR is enabled, and any suggestions on how to solve this without turning off BAR?
